# Firebase 403 errors from REST API

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I am trying to save data to my Firebase database from C# using the REST api.  I get 403 errors when I try to save the data (trying to save to a list).  I am able to save data to this list from angular (using AngularFyre), but I get a 403 every time I try from the REST api.  My database is setup with the default rules which currently allows reads and writes to everything and this appears to work as evidenced by the fact that I can save from Angular.

The url I'm posting to looks like this https://[mydb].firebaseio.com/subscriptions.   Here's the code I'm using:

```
    void SaveToFirebase<T>(T objectToSave, string url)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "PUT";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            var serializedData = jsonSerializer.Serialize(objectToSave, true);
            streamWriter.Write(serializedData);
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
        stream.Close();

        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            ThrowIfHttpSaveRequestFailed(request, response);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the problem was that I simply wasn't including .json in my url.  So the URL that was giving me a 403 looked like this https://[mydb].firebaseio.com/subscriptions/id and it needed to look like this: ttps://[mydb].firebaseio.com/subscriptions/id.json.  This fixed the 403 problem.

Comment: i added son similar issue i am getting